# how to let a submit button in a form do something before executing the action of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good evening, i have a HTML form that contains a submit button that does something other than executing the action of the form, i want these submit button to do an action first then do the  action of the form, that button do a nice jquery slideUp() but when i embed it in a form it does the action of the form and neglect the slideUp() behavior, what are the possible ways to let that button do the slideUp() first before submitting the form?

here's the form:

```
    <form action="AddNewCar" method="get">
            <table BORDER=2 BORDERCOLOR=YELLOW width="300px">
                <tr>
                    <td>Description: <input type="text" name="desc" /></td>
                    <td>Quantity:<input type="text" name="qunt" /></td>
                    <td>Price: <input type="text" name="price" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>CC.No: <input type="text" name="cc" /></td>
                    <td>Engine: <input type="text" name="engine" /></td>
                    <td>Cylinder.No: <input type="text" name="cylinder" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Max-speed: <input type="text" name="speed" /></td>
                    <td>Petrol-type: <input type="text" name="ptr-type" /></td>
                    <td>Petrol-capacity: <input type="text" name="ptr-cpcty" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" class="btn1" value="Add" onclick="addNewCar()" /></td>

                </tr>
            </table>




        </form>
```

and here's the script is supposed to execute before anything else:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
$(".btn1").click(function() {
        $('#toggleText').slideUp();
    });



</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: what is toggleText in your example there is no div with that id ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".btn1").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var self = this;
    $('#toggleText').slideUp('fast', function() {
         self.form.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the slide up in a method and call it on submit

```
<form action="AddNewCar" onsubmit="slideupmethod" method="get">

function slideupmethod(){
   $('#toggleText').slideUp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a submit button, which uses onclick to fire off a function, and then submit your form. For example.

The html button for submit

```
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" class="btn_submit" onclick="submitOrder()" />
```

your javascript function

```
//function called when submit button pressed
function submitOrder() {

    //perform client side form validation and other things

    //submit the form
    $('#yourFormId').submit();
}
```

Alternatively, using the button you currently have. You can prevent the form from submitting when the button is pressed, perform the required actions, and then submit the form.

javascript

```
$('form').submit(function(evt){
//prevent form from submitting
evt.preventDefault();
//do required actions

//submit form
$('form').submit();

});
```