# How to add a value to a textbox using a submit?

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

I have two submit buttons namely "Approve" and "Reject". Both of them go to one controller file so I set the controller file on the action tag of the form.

What I want is that when I click Approve, it sets the value of the hidden field named 'Decision' with 'Approved' and when I click 'Reject', the value of the hidden field will be 'Rejected' then the form will continue to submit to the designated controller.

However, the form continues to the controller but the decision field is empty.
Also, when I tried to put an 'alert' on the javascript function, it is not showing everytime I click the submit buttons eventhough I used the onClick tag.

Can someone suggest a working code for this? Thank you. :)

Comment: Post the code you have tried so far. Try to post a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe form actions have precedence over javascript and other stuff like animations.

To answer your question: you can make the submit buttons just normal buttons like so:

```
<input id='accept-button' type='button' name='accept' value='Accept' />
```

and add an event listener to it that changes the value of the hidden field when clicked then submits the form:

```
document.getElementById('accept-button').addEventListener("click", function () {
    var hiddenid = document.getElementById('hidden');
    var formid = document.getElementById('form-id');
    hiddenid.value = 'Accepted';
    formid.submit();
});
```

After a quick search I found a better solution from this [question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122966/how-to-let-a-submit-button-in-a-form-do-something-before-executing-the-action-of). It uses jquery though.

Comment: I figured out the answer in my own way.